# How to stop back button in HTML?

Tags: android, html

I am creating an Android quiz game using HTML. I wants a code or technique by which the player could not go back by leaving the current page. It's an Android game. Please help me how it can be done in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/axt1Lqoz/ (click on Share and then use the browser back button) and it will give you the basis of what you need.  Not a good idea to disable the browser controls - I recommend instead you show a dialog and tell the user they are leaving the game with a yes/no to continue.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Back Button Example</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center; padding:0;">
    <a href="#share" id="share">Share</a>
    <div class="share" style="">
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <p> Back button press please for control.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click touch', '#share', function(e) {
    $('.share').fadeIn();
  });
});

// geri butonunu yakalama
window.onhashchange = function(e) {
  //var oldURL = e.oldURL.split('#')[1];
  //var newURL = e.newURL.split('#')[1];

  if (oldURL == 'share') {
    //$('.share').fadeOut();
    //e.preventDefault();
    //return false;
  }
  //console.log('old:'+oldURL+' new:'+newURL);
}
</script>

<style>
.share{position:fixed; display:none; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,.8); color:white; padding:20px;
</style>
```